# How make a search bar view transparent in ios

Tags: iphone

Ha ii everybody,i want to make a view with searchbar like the image shown in below.I saw lots of application uses this.I have a search controller view in my application,when the user taps the button it redirected to the search-view ,but my need is search-view wants to in a transparent mode ,that we can saw the main view in behind the search view.Please look at my imagelink.[imagelink](http://lh6.ggpht.com/_ixq8Dp4ESMo/SYugD2Pnl9I/AAAAAAAAAEw/nzI3VbLlzVc/SearchView.jpg)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the backgroundColor to one that has less then 1.0 alpha to generate transparancy.

For example:

```
yourSearchView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.5];
```

Comment: i set the serchviews alpha to 0 ,i tried it but nothing happens.

Comment: 0.0 means it is totally transparant which means its like it's not there. Set it to a slightly higher value for more effect.

Comment: ,i set the background alpha to .90but nothing hapens.i want to see the main page behing of this view.like the image.

Comment: self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.5];iput this in viewdidload.

Comment: ,my search view is uiview controller,not a subview.is there any search option in ios for doing this?linke my image.

Comment: The view you made on your searchVC that is over your mainview is the one you need to change. Try making it completely black and then play with the alpha. If it isn't working you should check if your view is properly attached, if the frame is good or if it even exists at the time you need it.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried this now and it has a nice transparent effect in iOS7.

```
self.searchbar.backgroundImage = [[UIImage alloc]init];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the color to the same color of your background. First set the background image to an "empty" image, then set the backgroundColor to the same color of your view

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
```

Consider this solution is only right for underlying views with a color not an image